# Use of the verb ‘output’

Tags: word-usage, verbs, terminology, technical, computing

I need some advice on the use of **output** as a verb.

To put it in context, I am working on a desktop app that uses some of the functionality of MS Word. In the app, there is an element called a binding that obtains a specific piece of data from the database and displays it in a document after you use it.
As an example, this is a binding that displays a company's name:
[image]

Once I execute it, it gives me the actual name of my company – the one that is specified in a specific location in the database.

[image]

And the question is: is it OK to use the verb **output** as a synonym for retrieving and displaying data in this case?

An example would be the sentence "To output a company's name in an MS Word document, you need to do use the following binding". Another example could be "To output the number of employees in your MS Word report, you need to do the following".

I'll be thankful for any feedback.

Comment: You use "display" several times in the question, have you considered that as an option?

Comment: @KillingTime
Yes, I have been thinking about that actually. But, to me "display" is more like "to just show something", whereas in my case it is more like "to take some information out of something and put it in a different place". That is why I am personally leaning toward using Output.

Comment: @All Do not answer in comments. Write an answer.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for MS Word, Libre Writer, or other applications, to see the terminology they use? I could do that, but you could do it too. *What research have you done?*

Comment: "output" is commonly used among computer programmers as a verb. I don't think it's common among end users. [ux.se] might be a better place to ask about language used in user interfaces.

Comment: I've searched "output the name" in Stack Overflow and there are many results: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22output+the+name%22  Thus, it is used in programming but I'm no expert. Someone experienced can answer. Wiktionary lists the sense of the verb _output_ in computing also: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/output

Comment: I agree with Barmar that this is about precisionist usage, computerese, rather than mainstream English and belongs on User Experience.SE. 'Output' here and 'display' both seem not to reference the retrieval necessary. 'Retrieve and display' is clear.

Comment: I would use "auto-insert".